# Pytorch iter() runs endlessly or throws RecursionError

Tags: python, pytorch, iterator, pytorch-dataloader

I am having an issue with Pytorch DataLoader. Whenever I try to load the next batch via the iter()-function the function runs indefinitely. I have also tried running the function in Google Colab and it returns a RecursionError. Here is the iteration function:

```
def create_data_loader(df, tokenizer, max_len, batch_size):
    ds = PostTitleDataset(
        title = df["clean_title"].to_numpy(),
        label = df["6_way_label"].to_numpy(),
        tokenizer = tokenizer,
        max_len = max_len
    )
    
    return DataLoader(
        ds,
        batch_size = batch_size,
        num_workers = 0
    )

BATCH_SIZE = 16
MAX_LEN = 80

test_data_loader = create_data_loader(df_test, tokenizer, MAX_LEN, BATCH_SIZE)

**# This function runs indefinitely or gives me a RecursionError in Google Colab**
if __name__ == '__main__':
  data = next(iter(test_data_loader))
  data.keys()
```

Here is the error message from Google Colab. In Jupyter Notebook it just runs indefinitely without an error message:

> RecursionErrorTraceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> ----> 1 data = next(iter(test_data_loader))
> 2 data.keys()
>
> 5 frames ... last 1 frames repeated, from the frame below ...
>
> in **getitem**(self, item)
> 24         #batch = convert_to_batch(dataframe)
> 25
> ---> 26         title = self["clean_title"][item]
> 27         label = self["6_way_label"][item]
> 28
>
> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

**Does anyone know how to solve this issue and how to have the iter()-function run through successfully returning a batch?**

Just to provide full information, down below you will find my custom dataset class:

```
class PostTitleDataset(Dataset):
    
    def __init__(self, title, label, tokenizer, max_len):
        self.title = title,
        self.label = label,
        self. tokenizer = tokenizer,
        self.max_len = max_len
        
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.title)
    
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        
        #batch = convert_to_batch(dataframe)
        
        title = self["clean_title"][item]
        label = self["6_way_label"][item]
        
        # Encode text input content
        encoding = self.tokenizer(
            title,
            padding=True,
            truncation=True,
            add_special_tokens=True,
            return_token_type_ids=False,
            return_attention_mask=True,
            return_tensors="pt",
        )
        
        # Return first post title of batch as validation
        return {
            "clean title": title,
            "input_ids": encoding["input_ids"].flatten(),
            "attention_mask": encoding["attention_mask"].flatten(),
            "Label": torch.tensor(label, dtype=torch.long)
        }
```